# How to make ctest run test executables in a transient/temporary directory

Tags: cmake, ctest

How can I make ctest run each of my tests in a separate transient/temporary directory each time I run `$ make test` (or `$ctest`).

Let's say I have a test executable, `mytest.cpp` that does two things: 1) It asserts that a file called "foo.txt" does not exist in the current working directory and then 2) creates a file called "foo.txt".  Now I want to be able to run `make test` multiple times without `mytest.cpp` to fail.

I want to achieve this by asking cmake/ctest to run every test (in this example, one test) in its own temporary directory.

I've searched for solutions online and I've read through the `ctest` documentation.  In particular the `add_test` docs.  I can provide a "WORKING_DIRECTORY" to `add_test`.  This will run my test in that "WORKING_DIRECTORY".  However any changes made to this folder persist across multiple `make test` runs.  So the second time I run `make test` the test fails.

Here's a minimal, reproducible way of triggering the failure. One source file `mytest.cpp` that defines the test executable and a CMakeLists.txt file to build the code.

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (CMakeHelloWorld)
enable_testing()

add_executable (mytest mytest.cpp)
add_test( testname mytest)
```

and

```
// mytest.cpp
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

inline bool exists (const std::string& name) {
    std::ifstream f(name.c_str());
    return f.good();
}

int main() {
    assert(exists("foo.txt") == false);
    std::ofstream outfile ("foo.txt");
    outfile.close();
}
```

Series of command that generate the failure

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make
$ make test
$ make test
```

This will give

```
Running tests...
Test project /path/to/project
    Start 1: testname
1/1 Test #1: testname .........................***Exception: Other  0.25 sec

0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.26 sec

The following tests FAILED:
          1 - testname (OTHER_FAULT)
Errors while running CTest
make: *** [test] Error 8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, a testing framework provides some kind of pre-test (setup) and post-test (cleanup) tasks. [And so does CTest.](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/ctest/Testing-With-CTest#customizing-ctest)

Adding the following `CTestCustom.ctest` file to the build directory of your example makes the test succeed every time:

```
# CTestCustom.ctest
set(CTEST_CUSTOM_POST_TEST "rm foo.txt")
```

For more complex tasks, you may want to create a custom script, but that's the way to call it.

Comment: Thanks, @Stanley F. I've upvoted and accepted this as it surely is the best answer (:

I'll look into using the pre-test tasks and see how far I get.  If there are any good examples of how to make each test execute in temporary directories then I would be keen to hear about it.